# Adding to Javascript Object Without Replacing Child

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to run a for loop to create new javascript objects and add to an existing javascript object without replacing.

For example I am trying to create this as the output without the group[i] being overwritten every time ( and just adding the number[i] data ):

```
{
    "group1": {
        "number1": "data",
        "number2": "data",
        "number3": "data"
    },
    "group2": {
        "number1": "data",
        "number2": "data"
    }
}
```

My loop looks like this:

```
var array = [{
    "groupName": "group1",
    "number": "number1",
    "data": "data"
}, {
    "groupName": "group1",
    "number": "number2",
    "data": "data"
}, {
    "groupName": "group1",
    "number": "number3",
    "data": "data"
}, {
    "groupName": "group2",
    "number": "number1",
    "data": "data"
}, {
    "groupName": "group2",
    "number": "number2",
    "data": "data"
}]

var groupLinks = {};

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    groupLinks[array[i].groupName] = { 
        [array[i].number]: array[i].data

}
```

As you can see with this code, my loop is only going to replace "group1" and "group2" every time.

Comment: The whole `number1`, `number2`, etc thing looks unmaintainable. Why not just an array of `numbers`, eg `{group1: { numbers: ['data', 'data', 'data'] }}`?

Comment: @Phil This is the structure I need it in to place into a database (Firebase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would go about approaching this:

```js
var array = [{
    "groupName": "group1",
    "number": "number1",
    "data": "data"
}, {
    "groupName": "group1",
    "number": "number2",
    "data": "data"
}, {
    "groupName": "group1",
    "number": "number3",
    "data": "data"
}, {
    "groupName": "group2",
    "number": "number1",
    "data": "data"
}, {
    "groupName": "group2",
    "number": "number2",
    "data": "data"
}];

var groupLinks = {};

array.forEach(
    function (element)
    {
        var groupName = element.groupName;
        (groupLinks[groupName] = groupLinks[groupName] || {})
            [element.number] = element.data;

    }
);

console.log(groupLinks);
```

here I used the `||` operator to create a new group when none was present, overwriting the existing `groupLinks[groupName]` at each iteration, and I used a `forEach` construct to loop over array elements.

Comment: The || is very clever. I'm trying to wrap my head around why it works. Does the () give it special meaning?

Comment: @Darkrum `A || B` just means, take `A` if it's truthy (i.e. any object), otherwise take `B`.

Comment: Oh i see what's going on. That indentation pluse the lack of a  semi colon

Comment: @Darkrum it works just as well with `groupLinks[groupName] = groupLinks[groupName] || {};`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators for the `||` operator

Comment: Yeah i figured it out that indentation threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var array = [{
        "groupName": "group1",
        "number": "number1",
        "data": "data"
    }, {
        "groupName": "group1",
        "number": "number2",
        "data": "data"
    }, {
        "groupName": "group1",
        "number": "number3",
        "data": "data"
    }, {
        "groupName": "group2",
        "number": "number1",
        "data": "data"
    }, {
        "groupName": "group2",
        "number": "number2",
        "data": "data"
    }]

    var groupLinks = {};

    array.forEach(function(el){
       if(groupLinks[el.groupName]){
         groupLinks[el.groupName][el.number] = el.data
       }
       else{
         groupLinks[el.groupName] = {};
         groupLinks[el.groupName][el.number] = el.data
       }

    });

   console.log(groupLinks);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of a little ES2015, this reduce job should work for you

```js
let array = [{"groupName":"group1","number":"number1","data":"data"},{"groupName":"group1","number":"number2","data":"data"},{"groupName":"group1","number":"number3","data":"data"},{"groupName":"group2","number":"number1","data":"data"},{"groupName":"group2","number":"number2","data":"data"}];

let groupLinks = array.reduce((gl, group) => {
    gl[group.groupName] = Object.assign({
        [group.number]: group.data
    }, gl[group.groupName]);
    return gl;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(groupLinks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
    var groupLinks = {};

    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       var groupLinks2 = groupLinks[array[i].groupName];
       if(!groupLinks2){
           groupLinks2 ={};
           var a = array[i].number;
           groupLinks2[a] = array[i].data;
      }else{
         var a = array[i].number;
        groupLinks2[a] = array[i].data;
      }
      groupLinks[array[i].groupName] = groupLinks2;

   }
```